# Android cannot upgrade my database when first query is using readonly database

Tags: android, sqlite

So I've been so far relying heavily on the automated (well almost) `onCreate` / `onUpgrade` method of my `SQLite` database. It was all working fine, and I just had to change the version number of the database to have it run `onUpgrade` automatically.

But now, I'm running into that exception when trying to add a column to my database, and changing the version number:

```
SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version X to Y
```

Looking at my code, sure enough the first query of my application is a `SELECT` query, and I'm using `getReadableDatabase` to open a connection to it, because the request doesn't need write access.

So I was wondering, how should I solve such a problem? Should I use `getWritableDatabase` all the time? (as a workaround, that works to get my update to pass) Surely, if both methods exist that's because they are meant to be used and the connection is optimized for read-only access when needed? I wouldn't want to lose the benefit.

Comment: "Surely, if both methods exist that's because they are meant to be used and the connection is optimized for read-only access when needed?" -- there is no optimization AFAIK. It simply blocks calls to stuff like `execSQL()`. I have run into this too on occasion and cannot figure out for the life of me what's going on, particularly since it does not seem consistent. Using `getWriteableDatabase()` is probably a reasonable workaround.

Comment: That's weird... My current workaround is to have a method at the "start" of my application that does just getWritableDatabase() and close it, to check, create and upgrade the database if necessary. Ah well... (By the way @CommonsWare, I will use this comment to thank you for your many answers on Android questions in StackOverflow, consistently great and well informed, that helped me a lot. You rock!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround I used: have a method at the "start" of my application that does just `getWritableDatabase()` and closes it, so that it triggers all the needed create / update if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a syntax error: one of the fields was a SQL reserved word.
But to see that error message about the syntax I had to add

```
dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().close();
```

to `MainActivity.onCreate()`.

Answer (score -1):

Some time column name is repeating during create statement..

```
create table tbl (Col1 TEXT,Col2 INTEGER,Col3 INTEGER,Col1 INTEGER,Col5 INTEGER);
```

Like here Col1 is repeat twice...

Comment: To which question is this an answer to?

Comment: If you get this error..  "SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version X to Y"

Comment: If you look at the source (e.g. http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#245), the exception is thrown before any of the `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()` calls - nothing to do with your `create table` stuff.

Comment: This is workaround, i get this error due to repeating the column name, that`s way i write this workaround/solution...