# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 1

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting the following LogCat exception when trying to create an SQLite database:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 1

Here is my code:

```
import static android.provider.BaseColumns._ID;
import static org.inetizen.university_timetable.Constants.DAY_OF_WEEK;
import static org.inetizen.university_timetable.Constants.DURATION;
import static org.inetizen.university_timetable.Constants.MODULE_CODE;
import static org.inetizen.university_timetable.Constants.ROOM;
import static org.inetizen.university_timetable.Constants.START_TIME;
import static org.inetizen.university_timetable.Constants.TABLE_NAME;
import static org.inetizen.university_timetable.Constants.TYPE_OF_SESSION;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TimeTableData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "timetable.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

/** Create a helper object for the TimeTable database **/
public TimeTableData(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " + MODULE_CODE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL " + DAY_OF_WEEK + " TEXT NOT NULL "
            + START_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL " + DURATION
            + " INTEGER NOT NULL " + TYPE_OF_SESSION + " TEXT NOT NULL "
            + ROOM + " TEXT NOT NULL )");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Here is my LogCat:

> ```
> 05-09 12:32:04.525: I/Database(601): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near       "module_code": syntax error
> 05-09 12:32:04.525: E/Database(601): Failure 1 (near "module_code": syntax error) on   0x252588 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE table_name (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT     module_code TEXT NOT NULL day_of_week TEXT NOT NULL start_time INTEGER NOT NULL duration     INTEGER NOT NULL type_of_session TEXT NOT NULL room TEXT NOT NULL );'.
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601): Couldn't open timetable.db for writing (will try read-only):    
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "module_code": syntax error: CREATE TABLE table_name (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT module_code TEXT NOT NULL day_of_week TEXT NOT NULL start_time INTEGER NOT NULL duration INTEGER NOT NULL type_of_session TEXT NOT NULL room TEXT NOT NULL );
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTableData.onCreate(TimeTableData.java:26)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable.getClasses(TimeTable.java:57)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable.onCreate(TimeTable.java:46)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 05-09 12:32:04.535: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(601):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:04.545: D/AndroidRuntime(601): Shutting down VM
> 05-09 12:32:04.545: W/dalvikvm(601): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.inetizen.university_timetable/org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 4: /data/data/org.inetizen.university_timetable/databases/timetable.db
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 4: /data/data/org.inetizen.university_timetable/databases/timetable.db
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:170)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable.getClasses(TimeTable.java:57)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable.onCreate(TimeTable.java:46)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> 05-09 12:32:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  ... 11 more
> 05-09 12:32:07.325: I/Database(611): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "module_code": syntax error
> 05-09 12:32:07.325: E/Database(611): Failure 1 (near "module_code": syntax error) on 0x119778 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE table_name (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT module_code TEXT NOT NULL day_of_week TEXT NOT NULL start_time INTEGER NOT NULL duration INTEGER NOT NULL type_of_session TEXT NOT NULL room TEXT NOT NULL );'.
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611): Couldn't open timetable.db for writing (will try read-only):
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "module_code": syntax error: CREATE TABLE table_name (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT module_code TEXT NOT NULL day_of_week TEXT NOT NULL start_time INTEGER NOT NULL duration INTEGER NOT NULL type_of_session TEXT NOT NULL room TEXT NOT NULL );
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTableData.onCreate(TimeTableData.java:26)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable.getClasses(TimeTable.java:57)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable.onCreate(TimeTable.java:46)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 05-09 12:32:07.335: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(611):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:07.345: D/AndroidRuntime(611): Shutting down VM
> 05-09 12:32:07.345: W/dalvikvm(611): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.inetizen.university_timetable/org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 4: /data/data/org.inetizen.university_timetable/databases/timetable.db
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 4: /data/data/org.inetizen.university_timetable/databases/timetable.db
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:170)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable.getClasses(TimeTable.java:57)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at org.inetizen.university_timetable.TimeTable.onCreate(TimeTable.java:46)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> 05-09 12:32:07.355: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  ... 11 more
> ```

Any suggestions on how to resolve the exception?

Comment: set: version=2 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

Comment: Hi thanks for the speedy reply, I get the same error but cannot upgrade from version 0 to 2

Comment: plz try version 3 or 4 it will work

Comment: check your logcat, there is another error that causes creating / upgrading the database to fail. Maybe because you did not add a `,` after each column definition in the create statement

Comment: Here is a paste of the logcat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21253885/2106820

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SQL syntax you are using doesn't look to be correct, you're missing commas. Try with this:
`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + MODULE_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + DAY_OF_WEEK + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + START_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + DURATION + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + TYPE_OF_SESSION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ROOM + " TEXT NOT NULL)");`

Answer (score 2):

you can try **getWritableDatabase()**.
may this link will help you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your db.open method...  I would bet you are not opening the db as writable.  It should look something like this:

```
public GroceryDB open() throws SQLException {
    mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry I have this
         private Cursor getClasses(String[] args) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = timeTable.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM         timetable WHERE day_of_week = ? ORDER BY " + ORDER_BY, args);
      startManagingCursor(cursor);
      return cursor;
     }

Comment: Ah.  So much for the simple solution.