# Android map app, can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 1

Tags: android, dictionary, mapbox, nutiteq, mbtiles

I've been trying(for days now) to get an Android map app working. This app has to work offline and im only interested in displaying a small city, after seeing all of my choices and trying them all, it seems that [Nutiteq](http://www.nutiteq.com/) is a great choice, specifically the offline MBTiles option. After setting everything up, and using a .mbtiles file downloaded using [TileMill](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/), i get the following error:

```
No such table android_metadata
```

The .mbtile file i downloaded doesn't have this table, and i can't find which class made this query(if anyone can explain why it's needed great!!!); i tried updating my .mbtile file with Navicat to add this table with the desired locale column with the en_US value, and now it gives the following log error message:

```
can't upgrade read-only database from version 0 to 1
```

My questions are:

- Is there a way to bypass this whole android_metadata query? I mean, if it's not included on the .mbtile why is it needed afterwards?
- If you don't recommend bypassing it, how to fix my second error with the upgraded database?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using "SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS" flag when calling SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase() to avoid the android_metadata warning.

Comment: Can you give specific code snippet how do you open the file (add a layer)?

Comment: The opening is handled by SQLiteOpenHelper getReadableDatabase() method, which is troublesome because there is no clear call to the openDatabase() method on which i can use the flag suggested. Is that flag applyable elsewhere?

Comment: What is your device exactly? It is strange error. Nutiteq should not require android_metadata in mbtiles files, and it has worked for me with plain mbtiles databases (without android_metadata) on all the devices where I've tested it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21253885/2106820

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to modify the database during the upgrade?  If it's readonly, you probably can't modify it.  You could create a new one, though, and copy the data from the old to the new.

Comment: Actually, i got it yesterday but redoing the whole code, i still haven't worked out the last one with that error, but i'll give it a go as soon as i can, thanks for your answer